# Search User and places by gelocation through FaceBook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to search for User and Places Ids according to a given geolocation parameter in FB API.

for example, i want to get all users with name: "Mark", living near: "lat":39.57,"lng":2.65.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//***search user by geolocation:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&center=39.57,2.65&distance=1000&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN&limit=5000

**HEADER**:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?

**STRING**:
q=mark

**TYPE**:
type=user

**GEOLOCATION AND DISTANCE:**
center=39.57,2.65&distance=1000

**ACCESS_TOKEN:**
YOUR TOKEN ID.

**LIMIT**:
limit=5000

//***search places by location
**USA**:

graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN&limit=5000

**Palma de Mallorca:**

graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=39.57,2.65&distance=1000&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN&limit=5000

Comment: thank you very much.
the search places by location work fine.
but when i search for a user: despite i set different geolocation, I always receive the same list of users. 
example:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&center=39.57,2.65&distance=1000&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN&limit=5000

and 

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN&limit=5000

give me the same result despite of different geolocation parameters.

Comment: @MarkFreewind : I think there is no such feature anymore, you can not search users by their geolocation. You can search only for events, and places by geolocation.